# VMs with same name an IP

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, certificate, foreman

Does Foreman support managing several VMs with same name and IPs, but with different certname? for example:

- NAME         IP             CertName
- VMLinux001   10.0.0.2       VMLinux001@domain.com
- VMLinux001   10.0.0.2       VMLinux001@Another.com

I know puppet does, but ForeMan seems to use the VM hostname and mixed data coming from both.

Comment: I found the solution, edit the following file:
/etc/puppet/node.rb
change :
hostname     = puppet_facts['values']['fqdn'] || certname
for:
hostname     =  certname